# Android/Java: How to get the userId in the new OneSignal 4.0.0? (idsAvailable is deprecated and getPermissionSubscriptionState doesn't work)

Tags: java, android, onesignal

I upgraded onesignal by adding `implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.0.0'` and now some piece of code doesn't work.

Old code deprecated that doesn't work anymore:

```
        OneSignal.idsAvailable(new OneSignal.IdsAvailableHandler() {
            @Override
            public void idsAvailable(String userId, String registrationId) {


            }
        });
```

New code that doesn't work:

```
        String userId = OneSignal .getPermissionSubscriptionState().getSubscriptionStatus().getUserId();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install this:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup

and then the code is something like:

```
OSDeviceState deviceState = OneSignal.getDeviceState();
String userId = deviceState != null ? deviceState.getUserId() : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OneSignal.Default.PushSubscriptionStateChanged += PushSubscriptionStateChanged;

        private void PushSubscriptionStateChanged(PushSubscriptionState current, PushSubscriptionState previous)
        {
            if (current.isSubscribed)
            {
                 // consume current.userId + current.pushToken
            }
        }
```